# I can't convert a double to an int (Math.random)

Tags: java

```
int rando = (Math.random() * ((1-3) + 1)) + 1;
        System.out.println(rando + "\n");
```

Trying to print a random number 1-2, but it will only let me print double.

Comment: I have posted an answer with typecasted and correct formula please check.

Comment: penny byron - If one of the answers resolved your issue, you can help the community by marking that as accepted. An accepted answer helps future visitors use the solution confidently.

Answer (score 3):

```
    //(int) (Math.random() * (upper - lower)) + lower; 
    //uppar Limit is exclusive hence to get value between 1-2 UL shoude be 3
    int rando = (int) (Math.random() * (3 - 1)) + 1;
    System.out.println(rando + "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the result of `Math.random() * 2` into `int` because [`Math.random()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--) returns a `double` value and adding/subtracting/multiplying/dividing a `double` value with an `int` value also returns a `double` value. Casting the result of `Math.random() * 2` into `int`, will ensure that it will be either `0` or `1` and then you can add `1` to it to get the desired `int` value.

Another way of doing it can be by using  [`Random#nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt--) which will not require casting.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rando = (int) (Math.random() * 2) + 1;
        System.out.println(rando);

        // Second method
        Random random = new Random();
        int rand = random.nextInt(2) + 1;
        System.out.println(rand);
    }
}
```

**Output from a sample run:**

```
2
1
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, your code wouldn't even reach the print line giving you a compiler error. To answer your question, you need to do what is called `typecasting` in java. It is the process of converting the value of one data type to another.

```
int rando = (int)((Math.random() * ((3-1) + 1);
```

Comment: Apart from typecasting , Even the also formula is wrong @nisarg , I have already posted an answer , check ur values it isnt 1 or 2

Comment: I do agree with you, but the OP's question was that how does he/she NOT print in double. The formula I believe depends on the logic which OP wants to apply

Comment: one part of a question was "Trying to print a random number 1-2", You can still edit to correct it

Comment: Missed that! Deleting the post since your answer suffices that

Comment: its fine :) U can always update the answer to get what OP wanted or support the right one :) ..

Comment: It's casting, not typecasting, and this isn't a case of casting; it's conversion (casting doesn't alter the value).

Comment: @chrylis One data type is assigned to another by the user, using a cast operator then it is called "Type Casting". 

Conversion of one data type to another automatically by the compiler is called "Type Conversion". double to int is a "Type Casting"
Please lookup the details first before commenting and downvoting the answer.

Comment: You mean [these details](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.12)?